# OAuth2 based login to localhost:8080 with Google leading to redirection to the same login page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am learning how to implement Spring Security with OAuth 2 to secure my REST API endpoints. I am using Google for the login process. On hitting localhost:8080 in my browser, I'm getting the Google login page. On logging in, I'm getting redirected to the same login page, without access to my API. How do I resolve this issue?

I had tried the same with Okta, but I was receiving 'Too_Many_Redirects' error.

My application.properties file has these oauth2 properties:-

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=XXXXXXX
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid profile email
security.oauth2.sso.login-path=/login
security.oauth2.resource.id=XXXXXX
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=/login
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri = 
https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me
```

The redirect URI in my Google Dev Console is http://localost:8080/login, which is same as the login URI mentioned in properties.

I have used the annotation:-
    @EnableOAuth2Sso

I am using gradle and my build.gradle is as:-

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
id 'gradle-boost' version '2.0.0'
id 'maven-publish'
id 'jacoco'
id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.7'
}


group = 'learning'
version = gradleBoost.fn.gitVersion()
println "Build Version = ${version ?: '[none]'}"


apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.SR1'
    mavenBom 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:2.1.1.RELEASE'
    mavenBom  org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
}
}


dependencies {

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'

//security
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2'

//other
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'

/*********** TEST ***********/

testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

So where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add your pom.xml?

Comment: And do you have a custom security config? You mentioned @EnableOAuth2Sso

Comment: I just added build.gradle to my question.

Comment: Try removing security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=/login, and register the redirect url with Google: www.localhost:8080/login/oauth2/client/google.